# Can't Access the $stateParams properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

[image: can't update]
I can access `console.log($stateParams)` but I can't access the properties inside it say for example `console.log($stateParams.pageNo)` as you can see in screenshot.

Code:

```
admin.controller('adminCtrl', function($scope, adminService, $s‌​ tateParams, $state) {
    $scope.toggleSideBar = true;
    $scope.serviceData = adminService;
    console.log("Accessing $stateParams");
    console.log($stateParams);
    console.log("Accessing $stateParams.pageNo");
    console.log($stateParams.pageNo);
    $scope.handlePage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.serviceData.page = pageNo;
        $scope.serviceData.paginate();
    };
});
```

Comment: Please show the context (code!!!). The little blue `i` indicates that values might have changed - so it might be an async problem here

Comment: adding the code    admin.controller('adminCtrl',function($scope,adminService,$stateParams,$state){
   $scope.toggleSideBar=true;
   $scope.serviceData=adminService;
   console.log("Accessing $stateParams");
   console.log($stateParams);
   console.log("Accessing $stateParams.pageNo");
   console.log($stateParams.pageNo);
   $scope.handlePage=function(pageNo){
     $scope.serviceData.page=pageNo;
     $scope.serviceData.paginate();
   };
});

Comment: So like I said, it will be an async function. You can't access data from a async function before it executed

Comment: this is really strange except if the value has been modified between yours console.log(s) by an other function who run at same time.